# Hadoop- datanode and node manager not running

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have installed hadoop 2.8.0 on my mac OS sierra. When I give JPS command, I could not see datanode and nodemanager are not running?

Name node, resource manager, secondary name node are running.

Comment: Did you format them before running them?

Comment: Yes I formatted namenode using hadoop namenode -format.

Comment: Check your datanode and nodemanager logs for ERRORs.

Comment: can you give me the steps to do that. As i'm new to this..

Comment: For homebrew installation, the logs will be under `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.0/libexec/logs/`. Check the datanode log file for errors.

Comment: Please post the logs of datanode and node manager

Answer (score 0):

You should check all nodes' status by this command,

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

and you can't find all nodes, your node don't work. So you should check your missing nodes' setting.

If you find all node by the commnad, your jps command doesn't work, so you should remove `hsperfdata_*` folder from your `/tmp` folder.

Comment: thank you for the response. I just installed hadoop on MAC using homebrew and did all configurations. I checked the command hdfs dfsadmin -report. It gave      Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0

Comment: The report shows your datanodes don't work at all. You have to fix all nodes' setting, for example, `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml` and `getenforce`(SELinux), etc.